# Resize image as per items in list view

Tags: android, android-layout

Am using an image as background , a list view is shown on layout .Data(names) are coming from web call , showing the names in list view.Any number of names(1 to n) can come in response of web call.Currently image i am using cover the whole(height) of screen.

What i want is if only 1 name is coming in response , height of background image should be only to cover a single name , if two names are coming size should stretch to show 2 names & so on .Once the height of image reach the height of screen , then image should not stretch more list now will be scrollable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 9-pach image, check this http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html